# How Data migration achieve in Multitenant Application. How Seperate Schema Approach Is handled in multitenant Application?

Tags: multi-tenant

As per the Discussion https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/462765  I have Created the Sample multitenant Application ,In that code Schema is dynamically created by guid id as schema name

Everytime i registered into page ,the new guid id and schemas and tables are created .

if i add some properties into codes,when new tenant register means the property applied to that tenant.

But My question is if already registered tenant is asking i don't want the property telephone no and change the column to Email address means How i should handle in code first migration.is there any way to handle

2)how to recover the telephone columns table data and how to map that withhout dataloss?

3)if i  delete the particular column means the whole data will loss ?how i should handle that in multitenant application.

without affecting other tenant data how we can add ,delete and alter the properties in multitenant application?

can anyone explain with code level? can you understand my question